# Django Celery ubuntu 14.04

Tags: django, redis, celery

I'm attempting to deploy a django app on an ubuntu 14.04 server on digital ocean.

I understand that celery is for asynchronous tasks. The user does something and instead of waiting for an expensive task to execute they can go to another section of the site. Celery does this by using redis or another message broker. It makes a queue and workers execute the tasks on the queue. I'm trying to use this to make api calls less invasive to user experience.

As I deploy this to production I am very confused about where all of the stuff for celery 'lives'. I've seen posts saying I can do everything I want with celery through the admin page, and other posts have a supervisor file made that starts celery. When I try to make the supervisor file I get an error command at '/home/django/django_project/venv/bin/celery' is not executable.

Regarding the management of celery through the admin page I'm not sure how celery workers and queues are created and managed. I would like to schedule tasks through there but am in general very confused.

I would appreciate anyone clearing this up. 
Thank you

update: Celery beat is what I've chosen to go with. When I execute:

```
celery -A <proj> beat -l info -S django
```

This happens:

```
[2017-07-13 22:31:51,051: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2017-07-13 22:31:51,052: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2017-07-13 22:31:51,107: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task does it work!? (does_celery_work)
[2017-07-13 22:31:51,134: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2017-07-13 22:32:21,094: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task does it work!? (does_celery_work)
[2017-07-13 22:32:51,095: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task does it work!? (does_celery_work)
```

That's super cool! But the task isn't executing. It is a twilio task that texts a phone number every 30 seconds to prove the celery scheduled task is working.
The redis server is working fine when I ping it and I even double checked that it's on the correct port and pinged that port.
So would you go about getting celery beat to work automatically and making sure it works?

Answer (score 0):

did you try http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ? it will help you to see if the worker is setup correctly and also to see your tasks.

I found a good example of django celery redis https://gitlab.com/harveydf-tutorials/django-celery-realtime

Hope these help you.

Comment: Thank you! Flower was super helpful. However there are several tasks that fail:

    [W 170713 22:59:25 control:44] 'stats' inspect method failed
    [W 170713 22:59:25 control:44] 'active_queues' inspect method failed
    [W 170713 22:59:25 control:44] 'registered' inspect method failed
    [W 170713 22:59:25 control:44] 'scheduled' inspect method failed
    [W 170713 22:59:25 control:44] 'active' inspect method failed
    [W 170713 22:59:25 control:44] 'reserved' inspect method failed

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format for a comment. It connects to the redis localhost successfully then everything after that fails and no tasks are shown on port 5555 but the flower page does load!

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't know how to start a celery beat like I did above in tandem with flower. I think I need to use a supervisor file for that but I can never get it to work.

Comment: did you setup your broker url ? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html?highlight=BROKER_URL#broker-settings

Comment: also you need to have the celery worker running in order to celery beat to work

Comment: oh so before I do the celery beat command I have to have a worker running?

Comment: The broker url is working fine. It responds when I ping it and I've made sure it's the right port

Comment: yes, you need the worker running because celery beat is only queueing tasks in a determinate schedule but the worker is processing the tasks

Comment: Ok so it seems like I should be doing this in a supervisord task maybe. I try to get celery to spawn a worker using a supervisord task and am told that the command pointing to the celery binary in my virtualenv is not executable. 

I'm pretty sure I will have to make a supervisord task for the worker and the beat and flower right?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this post in the future here is how I configured celery to run from the django admin:

create a supervisord conf file in supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf
for the command I just put celery, not the path to the celery binary in my virtualenv. I don't know why that works but it does.

I will do the same for beat and flower.

```
[program:celery]
command=celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/django/django_project
user=root
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/django/django_project/logs/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/home/django/django_project/logs/celery-worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs=600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true


; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```